# C# Xml to Linq remove an item

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm trying to remove an item with xml to linq but I can't get it to work:

## Xml

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>Harry Potter und der Stein der Waisen</title>
        <isbn>1</isbn>
        <author>J. K. Rowling</author>
       <price>30</price>
    </book>
</books>
```

## DeleteItem

I'm trying to navigate to the specific element and then call `.Remove()`

```
public void DeleteItem(Book toRemove)
{
  var xmlDoc = this.xmlFileStorage.LoadXmlDocument();
  xmlDoc
      .Descendants("books")
          .Elements("book")
              .Where(x => 
                  x.Elements("title").Single(y => y.Value == toRemove.Title)
                        && x.Elements("author").Single(y => y.Value == toRemove.Author)
                        && x.Elements("isbn").Single(y => y.Value == toRemove.Isbn)
                        && x.Elements("price").Where(y => y.Value == toRemove.Price.ToString()))
                    .Remove();

    this.xmlFileStorage.SaveXmlDocument(xmlDoc);
}
```

I don't think the `.Single()` is the right approach... 
how can I get the exact record from the xml Document?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Currently you're using `Title` instead of `title`, which doesn't help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using `Element` instead of `Elements`, and casting the `XElement` to `string` instead of using `Value`. Combine that with using `Title` instead of `title` and it should be fine:

```
xmlDoc.Descendants("books")
      .Elements("book")
      .Where(x => (string) x.Element("title") == toRemove.Title
               && (string) x.Element("author") == toRemove.Author
               && (string) x.Element("isbn") == toRemove.Isbn
               && (string) x.Element("price") == toRemove.Price)
      .Remove();
```

This will remove *all* matching elements, of course. If you want to ensure that there's only one match, you could call `SingleOrDefault()`, check that the result isn't null, and then call `Remove` on the `XElement`.

Another option to consider is *just* matching on ISBN - that's effectively the identifier for the book, isn't it? If your book happens to have a different price, or the author has different punctuation, do you definitely want that to prevent the removal?

Comment: thank you Jon this worked like a charm and your explanation was very insightful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `First` if you want to remove the first matching node. Also, you need to use `element` instead of `Elements`. This should work for you:-

```
xmlDoc.Descendants("book").First(x => (string)x.Element("title") == toRemove.Title
                   && (string)x.Element("isbn") == toRemove.Author
                   && (string)x.Element("author") == toRemove.Isbn
                   && (string)x.Element("price") == toRemove.Price
                   ).Remove();

xmlDoc.Save(xmlPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use SelectSingleNode()

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//parentnode//childnode");
```

in this way you will access the required node use it with the linq and you will be able to delete it.

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//parentnode//childnode").Remove();
```

Comment: I'd personally rather express queries within code than worry about either escaping the attribute values I want to check for, or use parameters within XPath (which I gather is feasible but have never seen used). Your answer would be more applicable if you showed the full XPath appropriate to the question, including matching the specific book.

Comment: @JonSkeet majorly i work on these things and i suggested a way how i do it. I have used it and you can also try it it is possible. right now i am busy with something, but i will get back to you soon.

Comment: It's certainly *possible* with XPath - it just seems a hassle-laden way of doing it compared with the built-in querying within LINQ to XML.

Comment: ok boss you are right but it is more efficient and fast than LINQ to XML.

Comment: I'd rather write simple code and then optimize when it's proven to be necessary than need to worry about "XPath injection attacks" etc just for the sake of unrequired performance.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work to remove the values you want gone.

```
var model = xDoc.Descendants("book")
.Where(m => m.Element("element you want to match on to remove").Value == toRemove.ToString("value you want to match on"))
.FirstOrDefault();
```